# reverse string [JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

Don't worry I know how to reverse string (one word string :) )

```
> function reverse(s){
>     return s.split("").reverse().join(""); }
```

How to reverse a string in this way:

```
"Dady come home" -> "ydaD emoc emoh"
```

or:

```
('double  spaced  words') === 'elbuod  decaps  sdrow');
```

I spent with this couple hours today, becouse I'm learning, for any help I will be gratufull! Thanks!

**And please don't write full reply with code. :)** I just ask for some tips.

Comment: **Tip:** split words then use your current reverse function for each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split by space and then reverse each word

```
 string.split` `.map(a=>[...a].reverse().join``).join` `
```

```js
var string = "Dady come home";
console.log(string.split` `.map(a=>[...a].reverse().join``).join` `)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the sentence at each space `word.split(' ')`

Then cycle through each individual word and reverse their order `x.split('').reverse().join('');` (what you already have figured out :D)
I used `.map()` for this -- just a bit cleaner than a for loop -- feel free to learn more about the `.map()` method at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Once all the words have been reversed, stitch the array back together into a  string `strArray.join(' ');` but using an empty space to reconnect them.

```js
var str1 = "Hello";
var str2 = "Daddy come home";
var str3 = "double  spaced  words";

function reverseWords( word ){

  let output = '';
  
  // split the words based on spaces
  let subStrArray = word.split(' ');
  
  // reverse each word
  let updatedStrArray = subStrArray.map( (x) => {
    let result = '';
    if( x ){
      result = x.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
    return result;
  });
  
  // stitch back together as a string
  output = updatedStrArray.join(' ');
  
  console.log( output );
  
  return output;

}

let rev1 = reverseWords( str1 );
let rev2 = reverseWords( str2 );
let rev3 = reverseWords( str3 );

// making sure things can go forwards and backwards ...
reverseWords( rev1 );
reverseWords( rev2 );
reverseWords( rev3 );
```

Comment: it could be in a single line code

Comment: @sultan Without a doubt :)  Luis felipe De jesus Munoz provided a nice one-liner solution.  My take was just another approach where things are broken apart. Sometimes it's easier to read/understand things when it's spaced out.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using a regex that captures multiple whitespace chars, `/(\s+)/` for example. The  you will have an array of words and you can use Array.prototype.map (or a loop) to reverse each word individually and then Array.prototype.join to get the final result.

Comment: This is a comment, further, there are millons of answers for this scenario in SO.

Comment: @Ele This is an answer, not a comment, the OP specifically asked for tips without the full solution, so this is a complete answer to their question. Are their dupes with answers that don't have the full code in them?